# Error while importing the jobs form another server

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to import jenkins jobs from other server using Job Import Plugins. But i am getting below error while to the same.

```
FAILED - Expecting class com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder but got class org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob instead
```

FAILED - Expecting class com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder but got class hudson.model.FreeStyleProject instead

Comment: Looks like the target server is missing the Folders plugin. Compare the lists under "/systeminfo".

Comment: Folder plugin is installed. It get installed by default when we setup jenkins for the first time.

Comment: Is there any added details? What step was being executed? Stacktrace?

Comment: Below are the steps taken:
1) Under configure setting in Jenkins, added the remote jenkins details and save the changes.
2) then came to dashboard and click on import jobs plugin.
3) there select the remote server name and checked on search in folder, and click on query.
4) on the next page it gave the list of all the jobs from that remote jenkins server.
5) there checked "install plugins", "overwrite jobs", "import" and "disable" and then click on import.
6) after I click on import i got the mentioned error. not much details around that error.

Comment: What about in the system logs?

Comment: INFO org.jenkins.ci.plugins.jobimport.JobImportAction doImportInternal
Expecting class com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder but got class hudson.model.FreeStyleProject instead
java.io.IOException: Expecting class com.cloudbees.hudson.plugins.folder.Folder but got class hudson.model.FreeStyleProject instead
 at hudson.model.AbstractItem.updateByXml(AbstractItem.java:884)
 at org.jenkins.ci.plugins.jobimport.JobImportAction.doImportInternal(JobImportAction.java:218)
 at org.jenkins.ci.plugins.jobimport.JobImportAction.doImport(JobImportAction.java:138)

Comment: at org.jenkins.ci.plugins.jobimport.JobImportAction.doImport(JobImportAction.java:138)
 at java.lang.invoke.VirtualHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_V(VirtualHandle.java:85)
 at java.lang.invoke.FilterReturnHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_X(FilterReturnHandle.java:59)
 at java.lang.invoke.AsTypeHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_X(AsTypeHandle.java:49)
 at java.lang.invoke.InvokeGenericHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_X(InvokeGenericHandle.java:88)
 at java.lang.invoke.SpreadHandle.invokeExact_thunkArchetype_X(SpreadHandle.java:100)

Comment: Above is the logs from system logs.